# SQL Login created but not mapped - user already exists - is there any connection between?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, mapping, roles, restore

*Greetings,*

When I login into a particular MSSQL database as sa I see the following: somebody moved a database from server A to server B using **restore option**. I can see all the users in place (restored along with the database) - great. There are logins previously created on server A - great. All of those logins have **sysadmin** role. I think there's one problem - I don't see any **mappings done between logins and users** on server B (currently I have no access to Server A so I can't look at the configuration).

1. According to **security properties** - all of those 'local' database users are '**SQL user without login**' - but I'm sure a proper application uses those users on a regular basis and there are configuration files where passwords are stored.

**Question #1** - if there's a login with sysadmin role and there's a local database user of the same name (as login) - does the application use login or local db user in order to work properly? (there's no mapping between the two)

**Question #2** - should mapping be done between all the logins and corresponding database users when moved from one server to another? At the moment there isn't any mapping done and my cooworkers are using logins with sysadmin role to access whole database.

*Regards,*

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the most important information. Now it's there.

Answer (score 0):

1) If a particular login has the sysadmin role the application or person using this login can do anything on the database server. It is generally not considered good practice to have a lot of sysadmin users because it opens up the database server (and more) to security breaches.

2) Mapping SQL logins to database users makes sense if the users have minimal server-wide permissions and if you want to assign several certain data access rights in different databases. For example, you have a login X but users Y and Z and want to have read-only permissions for user Y in database Y but read-write permissions for user Z in database Z; in this case mapping can be useful.

There is something else you should be mindful of. If you backup a database (including database SQL users) on server A and restore the database on server B **and** the database users that are residing on server A were not created on server B using the same SID for the corresponding login(s) you end up with orphaned users, meaning the name of the login is not important to SQL Server but the SID of the login is.
You can find the SIDs in system login tables:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_logins
SELECT * FROM sys.syslogins
```

To make sure the login on both servers is exactly the same (same SID!) you have to create the logins using a script like this:

```
CREATE LOGIN MyTestUser WITH PASSWORD=N'!@MyTestPassword#$', SID=0x552C84CB83802C4A801C670265CCAFA4, DEFAULT_DATABASE=tempdb, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hi Thailo, thank you. What if I remap those database users using sp_change_users_login? Then, I guess, each user's sid equals new login's sid.